# Getting day of year and downloading files via ftp using DOY as part of file name

Tags: bash, ftp, cron, variable-assignment, heredoc

I currently have a bash script whose sole job is to login to a FTP server and download files everyday. Part of the filenames is a day of year (DOY). So I get the current date and use the `%j` option to obtain the DOY. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
doy=$(date +%j)
mget filename_$doy*
```

When this script runs, it not only gets the files for the current DOY, but also all those previous. So if today is DOY 260, it gets all the files from 0 to 260. I just want 260. The rest of my bash script is a mock-up from the following website: [Automatic/periodic FTP download using cron jobs](https://lookupnotes.blogspot.com/2013/03/automaticperiodic-ftp-download-using.html). What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Full script per @redneb 's request

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='ftp.server'   # change the ipaddress accordingly
USER='user'   # username also change
PASSWD='pass'    # password also change
ftp -inv $HOST<<EOF
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
bin
cd /filedirectory/
doy=$(date +%j)
mget filename_$doy*
bye
EOF
```

EDIT 2: @Cyrus' answer worked. Here is my final working script, in case anyone else needs help. You need to put in the bash commands before logging into the FTP server. Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='ftp.server'   # change the ipaddress accordingly
USER='user'   # username also change
PASSWD='pass'    # password also change
doy=$(date +%j)
ftp -inv $HOST<<EOF
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
bin
cd /filedirectory/
mget filename_$doy*
bye
EOF
```

Comment: One possibility is that `$doy` is not set when the `mget` line is run, and therefore that line becomes equivalent to `mget filename_*` (i.e. `$doy` is treated as the empty string). You can test this theory by adding a `echo $doy` right before the `mget` line.

Comment: Hmmm, yes I tried both `echo $doy` and `printf $doy` and neither printed out anything. If `$doy` isn't set yet once it gets to `mget`, how could this be fixed? Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You'll have to post the entire script for us to help you.

Comment: I edited my post @redneb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
doy=$(date +%j)
```

to a line before

```
ftp -inv $HOST<<EOF
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of this right before you posted this. I tried it but it didn't work. It makes sense though, that maybe once I login to the FTP server it doesn't recognize my bash commands?

Comment: This actually worked! I edited the original post to reflect my changes.

Comment: Yes, File Transfer Protocol can't handle a variable assignment.